# The location which i have selected in search bar should reflect in mydealers.php page

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented autocomplete search bar for my website. I will select location in the index.php page. The selected location from index.php page has to reflect to mydealers.php page also. but its not happening. instead it's showing some other location name.

Html Code

```
<div style=margin-left:500px;margin-top:-40px;width:500px>
  <?php
     echo " <select data-live-search='true' data-live-search-style='startsWith' class='selectpicker' id='locName'>";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT LocationName From arealistmain');
     $stmt->execute();
         while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo  " <option>" .$row['LocationName'] . "</option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";

  ?>
</div>
Java Script
 <!--AutoComplete Search bar-->
$(function() {
    $("#locName").autocomplete({

        minLength: 1,
        function(event) {
            var value = event.getAttribute('value')
            var locName = document.getElementById("locName").value;
            if (value.includes('&')) {
                value = value.replace("&", "%26");
            }
            if (locName == "") {
                alert("Please Select your Location");
            } else {
                window.location = "http://www.citycontact.in/MyDealers.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
});
    <!--Auto Complete For Categories-->
    function Demo(anchor) {
        var value = anchor.getAttribute('value')
        var locName=document.getElementById("locName").value;
        if(value.includes('&')){
            value = value.replace("&", "%26");
        }
       if(locName==""){
           alert("Please Select your Location");
       } else {
           window.location = "http://www.citycontact.in/MyDealers.php?id="+value+"&locName="+locName;
       }
    }
```

Comment: "some other location"...what other location? Something random?? Seems unlikely. Anyway it seems to me you didn't set up your autocomplete correctly - in the options you've supplied a callback function, but you haven't named it as belonging to a particular option, so autocomplete won't know what to do with it. So it's unlikely it would execute. Check the documentation and tutorials and ensure you set up the options correctly.

Comment: topmost location from the database..alphabetically says means from A

Comment: Ok. Please note my comments about your autocomplete setup as well. But one more thing I just noticed...attaching an autocomplete to a `<select` really makes no sense at all - the whole point of an autocomplete is to allow you to type a value in a textbox and then display a dynamic list of options. I can't see how this can ever be working for you in any way whatsoever. A `<select` doesn't allow any typing, and the list is not dynamically generated. Do you understand the concept of autocomplete? Look at the demos here to get the idea: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/